# Android how to populate list with rows from database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

Im trying to populate a list with the rows of a database with the first colum being the title of each list item then the other rows subtext of each list item, so far my tries arent working.

```
ListView browser = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.BrowsePO);
        SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("POTable.db",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM POTable" ,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        List<String> POnumbers= new ArrayList<String>();
        int totalPO = c.getCount();
        while(totalPO!=0)
        {
          String _PO = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("POnumber"));
            String _Lat = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Latitude"));
            String _Long = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Longitude"));
            POnumbers.add(new String( " " + _PO + " " + _Lat + " " + _Long));
            c.moveToNext();
            totalPO = totalPO -1;
        }
        c.close();
        ArrayAdapter array = new ArrayAdapter(this, POnumbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html) instead of an array adapter.

You should query your database on a background thread - e.g. in an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader.html). You then return a Cursor from your query, and pass it to your CursorAdapter. The adapter handles moving the cursor to the next/previous position, and you simple need to bind the data in the cursor to a view.

[This](http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html) might help.